# Redirect unauthenticated user to login by default on all pages

Tags: astrojs

Within an individual route, I know that I can get the user session and redirect to the homepage if the user is not authenticated.

But my site has many routes, and all but the homepage require authentication.

I don't want to accidentally expose one route because I forgot to mark it as requiring authentication.

Is there a way to indicate that *all* my routes require authentication by default (and specify that individual routes do *not*, as needed) rather than the other way around?

Comment: yes, https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/middleware/